# Google Dataflow design

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We need your guidance on the dataflow design for the below scenario.

Requirement:
We need to build a dataflow job to read dataflow MS SQL database and write to Bigquery.
We need the dataflow job to take as input “the list of table names” (source and target table names) to read from and write to the data.

Question:
On a daily schedule, would it be possible for a dataflow to take the list of tables (i.e. 50 table names) as input and copy data from source to target or should this be designed as 50 independent dataflow jobs.
Would dataflow automatically adjust the number of workers – without bringing down the source MS SQL server ?

Key Info:
Source: MS SQL database
Target: Bigquery
No of Table: 50
Schedule: Every day , say 8 am
Write Disposition: Write Truncate (or Write Append)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates) to be able to trigger it on a schedule. On that template, you have to define a input variable in which you can put your table list.

Then, in a same dataflow job, you can have 50 independent pipeline, each reading in a table and sinking the data in BigQuery. You can't run 50 dataflow jobs in parallel because of [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) (limit of 25 per projects). In addition, it will be less cost efficient.

Indeed, Dataflow is able to parallelize on the same worker different pipeline (in different thread) and to scale up and down the cluster size according to the workload requirements.